# How group by array values in mongo?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, grouping

Help me please.
I want to calculate the number of values for all the documents in the collection.
How can I solve my problem to get this result?

My documents:

```
'title' => 'Televisor # 1',
'networks'    => [12, 3],
'resolutions' => [7],
'interfaces'  => [13, 9],

'title' => 'Televisor # 2',
'networks'    => [12],
'resolutions' => [9],
'interfaces'  => [13, 9, 24],
```

I want to get this result

```
networks
 value 12, count 2
 value 3, count 1

resolutions
 value 7, count 1
 value 9, count 1

interfaces
 value 13, count 2
 value 9, count 2
 value 24, count 1
```

Comment: I try this aggregation, but only one array field 'networks' `db.collection.aggregate([
 {$unwind:"$network"},
 {$group:{_id: "$network", count:{$sum:1}}}
])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want with a **single** aggregation query:

```
db.yourDb.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $project: {
                "_id": 0,
                "title": 0
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $project: {
                "parts": [
                    { "value": "$networks" },
                    { "value": "$resolutions" },
                    { "value": "$interfaces" }
                ]
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $unwind: {
                "path": "$parts",
                "includeArrayIndex": "partIndex"
            }
        },

        // Stage 4
        {
            $project: {
                "value": "$parts.value",
                "partName": {
                    "$cond": {
                        "if": { "$eq": [ "$partIndex", 0 ] },
                        "then": "networks",
                        "else": {
                            "$cond": {
                                "if": { "$eq": [ "$partIndex", 1 ] },
                                "then": "resolutions",
                                "else": "interfaces"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 5
        {
            $unwind: {
                "path": "$value"
            }
        },

        // Stage 6
        {
            $group: {
                "_id": {
                    "partName": "$partName",
                    "value": "$value"
                },
                "count": { "$sum": 1 }
            }
        },

        // Stage 7
        {
            $project: {
                "_id": 0,
                "partName": "$_id.partName",
                "stats": {
                    "value": "$_id.value",
                    "count": "$count"
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 8
        {
            $group: {
                "_id": "$partName",
                "stats": { "$push": "$stats" }
            }
        },

    ]
);
```

The result of running this aggregation is:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "resolutions", 
    "stats" : [
        {
            "value" : 7.0, 
            "count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "value" : 9.0, 
            "count" : 1.0
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : "networks", 
    "stats" : [
        {
            "value" : 12.0, 
            "count" : 2.0
        }, 
        {
            "value" : 3.0, 
            "count" : 1.0
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : "interfaces", 
    "stats" : [
        {
            "value" : 24.0, 
            "count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "value" : 9.0, 
            "count" : 2.0
        }, 
        {
            "value" : 13.0, 
            "count" : 2.0
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm pretty sure it can be optimized a little bit, but you should get the key idea anyway.

Comment: Omg, you are magician! thx a lot, I was looking for a solution two weeks. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, the aggregation framework is flexible but requires time to learn. Would you mind accepting my answer if it solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Using simple find query and forEach loop may your problem get solved. If you can use mongo query without aggregation then please try out this:

```
var result = {network: [], resolution: [], interface: []};

db.new_collection.find({}).forEach( function(myDoc) {

  result['network'] = result['network'].concat(myDoc.networks);

  result['resolution'] = result['resolution'].concat(myDoc.resolutions);

  result['interface'] = result['interface'].concat(myDoc.interfaces);

})

printjson(result);
```

Into 'result' object you will get all collected array values then you can sort it as per the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any another way than executing three different queries.

```
db.mycol.aggregate([ {$unwind:"$network"}, {$group:{_id: "$network", count:{$sum:1}}} ])

db.mycol.aggregate([ {$unwind:"$interfaces"}, {$group:{_id: "$interfaces", count:{$sum:1}}} ])

db.mycol.aggregate([ {$unwind:"$resolutions"}, {$group:{_id: "$resolutions", count:{$sum:1}}} ])
```

If you're using node.js, then you can fire these commands using [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) either in serial or parallel and get a combined output.